# Why have I stopped listening to my favorite album?

Tags: knowledge, music, humor

Why have I recently stopped listening to my favorite Smashing Pumpkins album?
[image]

---

<sub>JK, I still love it.</sub>

Comment: I thought it was "Because Daughter Can't Find CD".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because you are

> **Tired of [Adore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adore_(album))!**

Noting that

> the notes given in the puzzle are (in the Do Re Mi... scale):
>  Ti Re Do Fa Do Re... or TiReD oF aDoRe.

Comment: TIL that "si" was renamed "ti". </showing my age>

Comment: @Jeffrey It was renamed in the 1800s, but only in the Anglophone world. That's why ti is a drink with jam and bread

Comment: @Jeffrey "si" still exists, but it refers to G# rather than B (in C major).

Comment: In general, sharps are indicated in solfege by changing the vowel to "i", producing "di", "ri", "fi", "si", and "li".  This obviously doesn't work for "mi" and "ti", but those notes rarely take sharps anyway, since they'd be enharmonic to "fa" and "do".